# prove, $\int_0^x \left (\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n \right ) \ dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Tags: analysis

Let $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nx^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R>0$ prove, $\displaystyle \int_0^x \left (\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n \right ) \ dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} $

The question gives a hint to use the mean value theorem, I have given it an attempt,

define $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$,

$g(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x f(t) \ dt - \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ then the derivative $g'(x) = 0$, so $g(x)$ is constant,

how would I use the mean value theorem from here? I suppose I could say there exists a point $c \in (-R,R)$ s.t. $g'(c) = \dfrac{g(-R) - g(R)}{-2R} = 0$ but what information does that give me?

Comment: Please avoid using display style in titles. It makes them too big.

Comment: I don't see what use the mean value theorem could be here. For $\lvert x\rvert < R$, the power series converges uniformly on the interval of integration, so we can interchange summation and integration. Or, we can, like you did, see that $g$ is constant, and since evidently $g(0) = 0$, the result follows. No MVT needed anywhere.

Comment: @DanielFischer you need MVT to conclude that there exists $c$ such that $g(c)=0$

Comment: @gt6989b How so? $g(0) = 0$ is immediate.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, that does work, but really curious why the hint was for the MVT

Comment: I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry, just being dumb

Comment: I'm realy curious to know how we can use the MVT to prove the equality. Notice that the common way to have the result is to prove the uniform convergence and then integrate term by term.